# Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core@2.9.7 Source Map URL: barba.umd.js.map

Tags: javascript, github, source-maps, barbajs, jsdelivr

I'm trying to install `BarbaJS` with a JS bundler for my GitHub-hosted website.  Using CDN, I include a line that installs BarbaJS but when I open the website I get a source map error:

[Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core@2.9.7 Source Map URL: barba.umd.js.map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDBqL.png)

Their [documentation](https://barba.js.org/docs/getstarted/install/) doesn't seem to mention this error.

Here is my script tag that installs the library:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core@2.9.7"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<script type="javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core@2.9.7"></script>
```

Adding the type made it work for me.

Comment: Thanks! I had this error: Source map error: Error: "request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/less
Source Map URL: less.min.js.map"

Your method fixed it.

Comment: In my case, adding type="javascript" stopped the script file to be loaded and did not solve the issue